# grails v3.3.9: how to keep scaffolded views separate from rest API

Tags: rest, grails, scaffolding

grails v3.3.9

I'd to be able to used scaffolded views /controllers but keep these **separate** from my rest API views and controllers.

I started my project app to generate jsonApi so i setup my UrlMappings with something like this

```
   ...
   "/api/sites"(resources:'site') {
        "/devices" (resources:'device')
    } ...
```

I then created my RestfulController in grails-app/controllers, and the default convention assumes your controller will be SiteController, and then you edit the grails-app/views/site with your gson templates for rest rendering.  so far so good.

Now you come to try scaffolded views - and the platform defaults start to break.

i created a new entry in UrlMappings like this, to direct the ui to its own controller

```
    "/ui/sites/$action?/$id?" (controller:"siteUI") {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

you can then create a new controller like this

```
   class SiteUIController {
       static scaffold = x.y.z.Site
   }
```

and run the app and access in the browser as /ui/sites - and it renders the list of sites.

however two immediate problems

1) my site has an Org domain ref (single ref) (with a toString()) and if i look at the link ref generated,  its looks like this, (where somehow the internals have generated a ref to the rest API controller and not to the HTML controller.)  Org link is

```
  http://localhost:8080/api/orgs/1
```

2) my site also has locations (site has many locations collection) (as yet no toString defined on that domain ).  When you look at the generated link it looks like this.  location link

```
http://localhost:8080/location/show/2
```

which is neither the rest/nor html controller !

I tried to cheat a little and saved my rest endpoint and did a generate-controller Site, and generate-views Site and messed about to put these in the right directories (views/siteUI, controller/siteUI etc ) and restored my saved rest endpoints back again.

This has helped a fraction as i can now go to the right view by typing the URL into the browser, say "/ui/sites/show/1" - and it renders ok.   but the links it renders wont work as all the defaults are wrong.

so what do i do ?  trying to change all the 'default'assumptions for scaffolding, views logic etc massive pain.  I don't want to go there.

Do i just do all the scaffolding first.  get that working, then add the rest controllers/views later?

I don't want to mix the UI with the Rest controllers  so that they can be worked on separately and independently, and any UI fiddling doesn't mess/break the rest points and vice versa

before i disappear into a right old mess - i'd like some guidance on best approach to keep these things apart without breaking all the BAU platform standards /logic in the framework - thats just too hard for me to handle.

Advice on best way to approach this scenario would be greatfully received.  I hoping that someone has been here and figured the best way to proceed.

Comment: "and if i look at the link ref generated, its looks like this... "http://localhost:8080/api/orgs/1 - there are any number of reasons that the link might look like that.  Can you show how you are generating the link?

Comment: had to rebuild the project - so condition have changed - sadly - however I think i've got round the problem by reading grails in action second addition.  Good old glen.  What i've done is moved all the rest controllers into grails-app/controller/rest/<name>Rest and changed my url mappings to be /api/resource (resources:<name>Rest.  having done that -ive regenerated html forms using generate-all - and moved the scaffolded controllers into there own ui sub directory.  I've got other issues with how to drive scaffolds but thats another day.    Ill update below to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer in Grails in Action - second edition page 332.

Sometimes the convention over convention can be confusing.  Essentially when declaring something like this in the UrlMappings:

```
    "/api/sites"(resources:'site') {
        "/devices" (resources:'device')
```

You might think the resources name refers to the domain class, actually its the name of the controller class:

So if you name the mapping like this

```
    "/api/sites"(resources:'siteRest') {
        "/devices" (resources:'deviceRest')
```

it's going to push the requests to a siteRest controller.

In addition, rather than many controllers all lying at one level in grails-app/controllers, it's not necessary.

Essentially if you create something like two sub directories, say  /rest, and /ui, and put the respective controllers in each (e.g. /rest/siteRestController.groovy , and /ui/siteController.groovy) then the url resolution mechanism is looking for the `<stem>` name matches under the grails-app/controllers directory.  So the primary requirement is that the controller names are unique.

The default mapping, then picks up and process any -generate-all/controller scaffolded controllers.

```
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?" {
        constraints {
            // apply constraints here
        }
    }
```

This lets you do you rest explorations away from your HTML ones and it stops you having to fight the framework.

There are other difficulties if you want play with the fields plugin - but sadly that will have to be saved for another post.

Views I suspect get matched the same way - I'm not sure - but I've left all the views at the same level in grails-app/views at the moment (e.g. site, and siteRest folders are side by side in grails-app/views).

Now you can use say generate-all x.y.x.DomainClass, and move the generated files into your required controller structure.

PS I'm using intellij, and I have had problems with the IDE caching and complaining that it can/can't find stuff when doing Application 'run'. Basically if you try the Grails view and 'boot-run', and at it works but your IDE is complaining, then you have the problem.

If you select the package area (services, domains etc) and right click and find the 'rebuild' option half way down - this seems to reset the cache in that area and your run action action on Application in the IDE starts working again.  This seems particularly sensitive to changes in your domain models and possible grails data services generated by generate-all. Doing the rebuild action seems to clear the caches and gets you back and working again.

If you want to see some of this structure you can look at this project on GitHub which shows workings to date

[Sample](https://github.com/woodmawa/LCM-network-app).